# How to Copy Sharepoint document Folder From one library to another library in K2 Blackpearl

Tags: sharepoint-2013, k2

I Have two Document Libraries in Sharepoint Site like Submissions and Submissions Archieve.in Submissions i have Some Document **Folders**.i want to Copy the Document **Folder** from SUbmissions to Submissions Archieve by using **K2 Blackpearl**.
Is it Possible ?
How Can We do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the available methods in the various sharepoint service brokers, I don´t think you can do that in one shot.

The solution I am suggesting is to first list the folder(s), then create them in the second site. Then you need to list the documents and copy them.

I would use the **Sharepoint Content** broker. You will find the folliwing methods:

1. Get Folders
2. Create Folder
3. Copy Document

Since you have several documents, you will need to make a loop. The way it works in K2 Blackpearl is that you need to go to the advanced configuration of the destinations of an activity and select **Plan per Slot**.
I think the best is to use the second option: **Select a list field...**

Make sure you select a field that can uniquely identify your document, you will need that within the activity, this will be the 'current' item within the loop.

I hope this helps,

Best regards